# Time window compaction strategy on data with TTLed inserts followed by TTLed updates

Tags: cassandra

I am facing problem with cassandra compaction on table that stores event data. These events are generated from censors and have associated TTL. By default each event has TTL of 1 day. Few events have different TTL like 7/10/30 which is business requirement. Few events can have TTL of 5 years if event needs to be stored. More than 98% of rows have TTL of 1 day.

Although minor compaction is triggered from time to time, disk usage are constantly increasing. This is because of how SizeTierd compaction-strategy works i.e. it would choose table of similar size for compaction. This creates few huge tables which aren't compacted for long time. Presence of few large table would increase average SSTable size and compaction is run less frequently. Looks like STCS is not right choice. In load-test env, I added data to tables and switched to leveled compaction-strategy. With LCS disk space was reclaimed till certain point and then disk usage were constant. CPU was also less compared to STCS. However time window compaction-strategy looks more promising as it works well for time series TTLed data. I am going to test TWCS with my dataset. Mean while I am trying to find answer for few queries to which I didn't find answer or whatever I found was not clear to me.

In my use case, event is added to table with associated TTL. Then there are 5 more updates on same event within next minute. Updates are not made on single column, instead complete row is re-written with new TTL(which is same for al columns). This new TTL is liked to be slightly less than previous TTL. For example, event is created with TTL of 86400 seconds. It is updated after 5 second then new TTL would be 86395. Further update would be with new TTL which would be slightly less than 86395. After 4-5 updates, no update would be made to more than 99% rows. 1% rows would be re-written with TTL of 5 years.

1. From what I read: TWCS is for data inserted with immutable TTL. Does
   this mean I should not use TWCS?
2. Also out of order writes are not well handled by TWCS. If event is
   created at 10 AM on 5th Sep with 1 day TTL and same event row is
   re-written with TTL of 5 years on 10th or 12th Sep, would that be
   our of order write? I suppose out of order would be when I am
   setting timestamp on data while adding data to DB or something that
   would be caused by read repair.

Any guidance/suggestion will be appreciated!

NOTE: I am using cassandra 2.2.8, so I'll be creating jar for TWCS and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

TWCS is a great option under certain circumstances. Here are the things to keep in mind:

1) One of the big benefits of TWCS is that merging/reconciliation among sstables does not occur. The oldest one is simply "lopped" off. Because of that, you don't want to have rows/cells span multiple "buckets/windows".
  For example, If you insert a single column during one window and then the next window you insert a different column (i.e. an update of the same row but different column at a later period of time). Instead of compaction creating a single row with both columns, TWCS would lop one of the columns off (the oldest). Actually I am not sure if TWCS will even allows this to occur, but was giving you an example of what would happen if it did. In this example, I believe TWCS will disallow the removal of either sstable until both windows expire. Not 100% sure though. Either way, avoid this scenario.

2) TWCS has similar problems when out-of-time writes occur (overlap). There is a great article by the last pickle that explains this:

```
https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/12/08/TWCS-part1.html
```

Overlap can occur by repair or from an old compaction (i.e. if you were using STCS and then switched to TWCS, some of the sstables may overlap).

If there is overlap, say, between 2 sstables, you have to wait for both sstables to completely expire before TWCS can remove either of them, and when it does, both with be removed.

If you avoid both scenarios described above, TWCS is very efficient due to the nature of how it cleans things up - no more merging sstables. Simply remove the oldest window.

When you do set up TWCS, you have to remember that the oldest window gets removed after the TTLs expire and GC Grace passes as well - don't forget to add that part. Having a varying TTL number among rows, as you have described, may delay windows from getting removed. If you want to see what is either blocking TWCS from removing a sstable or what the sstables look like, you can use sstableexpiredblockers or the script in the above mentioned URL (which is essentially sstablemetadata with some fancy scripting).

Hopefully that helps.

-Jim